# Compute number of users clicking different events in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table called "alerts" that looks like this.

```
user_id event   alert_type       eventtime
1       clk       s         January, 19 2037 12:16:21
2       clk       b         January, 19 2037 00:28:25
3       clk       b         January, 19 2037 02:44:23
3       clk       b         January, 19 2037 00:16:25
1       clk       b         January, 19 2037 02:28:25
9       clk       s         January, 19 2037 22:40:25
9       clk       s         January, 19 2037 03:14:07
2       clk       b         January, 19 2037 03:22:07
6       clk       b         January, 19 2037 05:21:07
9       clk       p         January, 19 2037 15:24:07
3       clk       p         January, 19 2037 05:34:07
10      clk       s         January, 19 2037 12:39:07
4       clk       b         January, 19 2037 09:14:07
4       clk       s         January, 19 2037 09:34:07
1       clk       s         January, 19 2037 09:54:07
8       clk       b         January, 19 2037 13:14:07
8       clk       p         January, 19 2037 10:24:07
8       clk       p         January, 19 2037 13:45:07
10      clk       b         January, 19 2037 13:51:07
4       clk       b         January, 19 2037 14:14:07
12      clk       p         January, 19 2037 15:14:07
1       clk       s         January, 19 2037 00:44:07
10      clk       s         January, 19 2037 08:14:07
12      clk       s         January, 19 2037 16:24:07
7       clk       p         January, 19 2037 06:53:07
6       clk       b         January, 19 2037 20:14:07
7       clk       b         January, 19 2037 20:23:07
```

Given an alert_type, I am trying to compute how many users clicked an alert as their **first alert** in the given day.

My desired output is

```
alert_type  Count of Users
b                4
p                3
s                3
```

I am trying to do it this way but I am not getting exactly what I want

```
SELECT count(user_id) AS Count of Users, alert_type, MIN(eventtime)
FROM  alerts
GROUP BY alert_type
ORDER BY alert_type DESC;
```

Kindly provide some inputs to achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method to get the first alert per user in a day:

```
select alert_type, count(*) as `Total Number of Users`
from alerts a
where a.eventtime = (select min(a2.eventtime)
                     from alerts a2
                     where a2.user_id = a.user_id and
                           date(a2.eventtime) = date(a.eventtime)
                    )
group by alert_type;
```